# a client/server program using java won't work

Tags: java, client-server

I'm trying to create a client/server program with java.

when the client connect to the server, the server will show him a message to enter the first value when the user write the first value the server sends him a message to write the sencd value when the user write the second value the server will show him a list of operations ans wait until the client write the number of the operation and then the server will send him the result of this operation.

When I write the program's code and run the server and then the client, it doesn't do any thing the server is blocked from doing anything, also the client.

this is the code I tried :

**for the client :**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;


public class Client {

    final static String ADRSS = "localhost";
    final static int PORT = 1234;
     static Socket s = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try{


                Scanner cn = new Scanner(System.in);
                s = new Socket(ADRSS, PORT);
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                in.readLine();
            out.println(cn.nextLine());
            out.flush();
            in.readLine();
            out.println(cn.nextLine());
            out.flush();
            in.readLine();
            out.println(cn.nextLine());
            out.flush();

            System.out.println("Res = " + in.readLine());
            out.flush();

        }
        catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();

        }


    }

}
```

**for the server:**

```
  import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Server {


    final static int PORT = 1234;
    private static ServerSocket server;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Socket s = null;
        try {
        server = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        s = server.accept();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        out.println("Donner le premier nombre : ");
        out.flush();
        double n1 = Double.parseDouble(in.readLine());
        out.println("Donner le deuxiéme nombre : ");
        out.flush();
        double n2 = Double.parseDouble(in.readLine());

        out.println("Donner l'op : ");
        out.flush();

        String choix = in.readLine();
        String res = null;

        switch(choix){

            case "1" :
                res = String.valueOf(n1 + n2);
                break;
            case "2" : 
                res = String.valueOf(n1 - n2);
                break;
            case "3" :
                res = String.valueOf(n1 * n2);
                break;
            case "4" :
                res = (n2 == 0) ? "Impossible d'éfectuer l'op" : String.valueOf(n1 / n2);
                break;
            default :
                res = "erreur";
            }

        out.println(res);
        out.flush();

        }catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try{
                s.close();
            }catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Looks like at least server should print some output, once connection works. How can you tell the programs are "blocked"? Maybe you should try printing something out on System.err to make sure that program gets past connection?

Comment: Do you enter anything in the client's standard input? Because it's waiting for you to enter 3 lines. And the server is waiting for the 3 lines from the client.

Comment: @JBNizet yes I enter inputs in the client side but nothing happens

Comment: @TNW The server should print a message in the client server at the first time but it doesn't

Comment: When debugging without a debugger, add sufficient debug traces. You're reading 3 lines from the server without printing them anywhere. So you're unable to understand what really happens. Of course, using a debugger would be a better solution. Also, why do you have a loop on the client trying to open the same socket over and over again?

Comment: It "looks" like both the client and server are writing at the same time, but neither are sending a line terminator or reading each others results...

Answer (score 1):

`PrintWriter` doesn't flush output after you use regular `print` (refer to [documentation of PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html)). You'd have to flush it manually. However, the real reason is your client waits for a line with newline, which never happens. Changing to `out.println` on the server side should make this running, also covering the flushes.

Answer (score 0):

first, after every print in the server, add

```
out.flush();
```

second, you are asking for nextLine() but printing without \n ,
either add \n to end of each string or use out.println